# how do you convert a date string that contains a monthname to a datetime?

Tags: powershell, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I am sure this ust be simple, but the search engines lead me articals that answer everything but this :-(

I have a string "13 February 2023 13:45:40" that I need to convert to a datetime so I may do a comparison

How you cast a date like this? Does it need a specialist module thats a little smarter then me hacking around with parseextract or regex?

Thanks oh wise ones

Comment: As simple as that: `Get-Date "13 February 2023 13:45:40"`

Comment: `[datetime]"13 February 2023 13:45:40"`

Answer (score 2):

The date format specifier for the full month name is `MMMM`, use this with `[datetime]::ParseExact()`:

```
$dateString   = "13 February 2023 13:45:40"
$formatString = 'dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'
$cultureInfo  = [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US')

[datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, $formatString, $cultureInfo)
```

Replace `en-US` with the appropriate culture identifier if you need to parse timestamps in other languages:

```
$dateString   = "13 février 2023 13:45:40"
$formatString = 'dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss'
$cultureInfo  = [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('fr-FR')

[datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, $formatString, $cultureInfo)
```

Answer (score 2):

- `13 February 2023 13:45:40` uses a string format that is directly **recognized as a standard format by the [*invariant culture*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)** (`[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture`, an immutable culture meant for programmatic use, based on - but distinct from - the `en-US` culture).
- **Using a [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) *cast* in PowerShell *always* uses the invariant culture**, so a cast with a standard format recognized by that culture can safely be used *irrespective of what the current culture is*.

  - *Caveat*: Passing such strings to [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date)'s `-Date` parameter is *not* safe, because they are subject to interpretation by the *current* culture's rules first, due to an unfortunate inconsistency in PowerShell's parameter-binding that won't be fixed, for the sake of backward compatibility - see [GitHub issue #6989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989)

Therefore:

```bash
[datetime] "13 February 2023 13:45:40"
```

To **handle formats *not* recognized by the invariant culture**:

- If they are *standard* formats recognized by the *current* / a *specific* culture, use [`[datetime]::Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.Parse):

  - Use `[datetime]::Parse($string)` to parse based on the *current* culture.
  - Use, e.g., `[datetime]::Parse($string, [cultureinfo] 'fr-FR')` to parse based on a *given* culture, such as `fr-FR` (French, France) in this example.
- Otherwise, *custom parsing* based on custom format strings passed to [`[datetime]::ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ParseExact) is required, as shown in [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75536823/45375).

  - Note: To perform custom parsing based on the *invariant* culture, use 
    `[cultureinfo] ''` (sic) as the `provider` argument.
- Both methods above also have `Try`-prefixed variants, which signal via a `[bool]` return value whether parsing is possible, and accept an optional `[ref]` argument to receive the result of the conversion.

A few examples, all of which are equivalent:

```bash
# The input string.
$dateString = '13 February 2023 13:45:40'

# OK - the [datetime] cast automatically recognizes the format 
# in the context of the *invariant* culture.
[datetime] $dateString

# Ditto, referencing the invariant culture explicitly.
[datetime]::Parse($dateString, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)

# Ditto, with an explicit format string, using [cultureinfo] ''
# as a more concise alternative to [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
[datetime]::ParseExact($dateString, 'dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss', [cultureinfo] '')

# .Try*() variants.

# Initialize the result variable.
# For the method-overload resolution below to work as expected,
# be sure to type-constrain it as [datetime].
[datetime] $dtResult = 0

# .TryParse()
$ok = [datetime]::TryParse(
  $dateString, 
  [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture, 
  [ref] $dtResult
)
# Result
[pscustomobject] @{
  CouldParse = $ok
  Result = $dtresult
}

# .TryParseExact()
$ok = [datetime]::TryParseExact(
  $dateString,
  'dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss', 
  [cultureinfo] '',
  'None',   # [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyle]::None
  [ref] $dtResult
)
# Result
[pscustomobject] @{
  CouldParse = $ok
  Result = $dtresult
}
```